# change model fields automatically when view changed in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a pop up with plenty of options which can be edited - this is a Backbone View.
I have a model which is simple POCO that stores those options. It's quite hard to write each view event handler to update the model's corresponding values.

How do I update the model automatically when its view fields change?

Assume I have textbox `Name` which corresponds to `model.name`. 
I need to update `model.name` automatically when I enter a new name in the textbox.  Is it possible?

I know that this way will not be mvc, but mvvm, and maybe it's better to use knockout.js here, but I already have some code for backbone, so hope it is possible to find some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your form to model updates with [Backbone Forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms).

This plugin will allow you to update the model automatically when related view fields have changes.

Answer (score 0):

From inside the view, you'd simply redeclare it with this. `this.model = SomeOtherModel;`